# Register member during checkout doesn't work in Store2 [solved]

Tags: expresso-store

**Edit: Problem solved in store update. Just download and install it.**

After installing Store 2 on a new site, i am no longer able to register members during checkout. To be sure, I also tried with the code I can confirm works on store 1, but it doesn't work on store 2. My form looks like this.

I have also enabled "Allow New Member Registrations" in EE.

If anyone can spot my problem, or give me some direction, it would keep me from ripping my hair out and be much appreciated! Thanks

```
{exp:store:checkout 
form_class="form default"
next="butikk/personalia"}

{if no_items}
    {redirect="butikk/handlevogn"}
{/if}

<div class="two-col">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Faktureringsadresse</h2>
        <label for="">Fornavn</label>
        {field:billing_first_name} {error:billing_first_name}
        <label for="">Etternavn</label>
        {field:billing_last_name} {error:billing_last_name}
        <label for="">Adresse</label>
        {field:billing_address1} {error:billing_address1}
        <label for="">Postnummer</label>
        {field:billing_postcode} {error:billing_postcode}
        <label for="">Sted</label>
        {field:billing_address2} {error:billing_address2}
        <label for="">Land</label>
        {field:billing_country} {error:billing_country}
        <div class="bump"></div>
        <label for="">Telefon</label>
        {field:billing_phone} {error:billing_phone}
        <label for="">E-post</label>
        {field:order_email} {error:order_email}

        <span class="create-accountt">
            <label for="password">Passord</label>
            {field:password} {error:password}
            <label for="password_confirm">Bekreft passord</label>
            {field:password_confirm} {error:password_confirm}
        </span>
        <label for="register_member" class="inline toggle-create-account">
            {field:register_member} Opprett konto (valgfritt)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Leveringsadresse</h2>
        <span class="same-as">
            <label for="">Fornavn</label>
            {field:shipping_first_name} {error:shipping_first_name}
            <label for="">Etternavn</label>
            {field:shipping_last_name} {error:shipping_last_name}
            <label for="shipping_address1">Adresse</label>
            {field:shipping_address1} {error:shipping_address1}
            <label for="shipping_postcode">Postnummer</label>
            {field:shipping_postcode} {error:shipping_postcode}
            <label for="">Sted</label>
            {field:shipping_address2} {error:shipping_address2}
            <label for="shipping_country">Land</label>
            {field:shipping_country} {error:shipping_country}
            <div class="bump"></div>
            <label for="shipping_phone">Telefon</label>
            {field:shipping_phone} {error:shipping_phone}
        </span>
        <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="inline toggle-same-as">
            {field:shipping_same_as_billing} Samme som faktureringsadresse
        </label>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .two-col -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<span class="right">
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Fortsett" class="btn-flat green">
</span>
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: There is a known issue in v2.0.2 when registering members during checkout. We will have a fix out for this very soon :)

Comment: I got the update with the fix in version 2.0.3 - thanks.

Comment: Fantastic, update fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue and fixed in the v2.0.3 release yesterday :)

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_203